# React Native: android emulator won't show up developer menu

Tags: android, react-native

Cmd-M (in Mac) is supposed to bring up the dev menu in android emulator, but when I press cmd-M, it shows the pan gesture(?) as shown in the screenshot.

How can I open up the react native dev menu?

`adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU` doesn't show up the menu either..

[image]

I can't find menu button either?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Had exact the same problem and could not open the developer menu neither with `ctrl + M` nor with `adb shell input keyevent 82`. `ctrl` would also show this strange gesture object.

Turned out I had run the app in non-development mode (done with expo via `expo start --no-dev`) and the menu is only enabled in development mode. After `expo start --dev` it works like a charm.

Comment: As a beginner in React Native, this saved my life, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can open it from the option button of the emulator or with this command adb shell input keyevent 82

Comment: can't find the option button .. I tried every button on the screenshot..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,

I was trying a JavaScript function in React Native and I didn't need to render anything for it, my screen was just empty.

Developer menu wasn't opening with Ctrl + M on Windows,
when I just try to render a simple text on screen, Ctrl + M started working.

Let's render something.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I was facing the same error and switching to debug mode resolved the issue for me. Reload and developer option won't work if you are testing using release build.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you need to use `Ctrl+D` to open the Developer Settings using the Android emulator.

Answer (score -4):

In order to open up the Developer menu on an Android Emulator press ⌘M when running in an Android emulator on Mac OS and Ctrl+M on Windows and Linux.

Comment: You are repeating what the documentation and the question say, it looks like you didn't even read the question.